# Erasing part of line vector outside raster region using GRASS?

Tags: grass-gis, erase, grass-7.4

I need to delete all the vector 'part' that it's outside the yellow raster region.

How can I do it?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yellow = raster

Black = vector

1) Polygonize the raster: create a polygon of the yellow area (https://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.to.vect.html)

2) Clip the black vector with the yellow polygon (https://grass.osgeo.org/grass76/manuals/v.clip.html).

you don't erase the black vector, instead you extract the part you want to keep